# Itunes library on multiple computers

Tags: itunes, multiple-computers

We have our Itunes library stored on our Macbook.  My son has an ipod classic that he has uploaded with a good amount of music from our library.  He is going away to college and wants the ability to continue to download songs, sync his ipod to get those songs but not lose the songs he has already uploaded.
The only way that I can think of for this to work is to get him an external drive; copy the library to this drive and have him take it with him to college.
Will this work?  Is the best option?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will work but there's also the point that only an ipod/iphone can be synced to one system at a time, so everytime he switches systems he has to erase everything and re-sync everything again.

The way to avoid this, is to make sure the itunes configuration files are identical on both systems, this way itunes thinks that your still using the same phone on the same systems.

Answer (score 0):

They only other thing that I can think of is setting up a server that he can access the files from anywhere.  That's a pretty intensive process for those that don't know much about networking.

I personally use ampache to stream the audio if that's what your looking for.

You can also use mediamonkey or winamp to sync the ipod so that you don't have to clear the ipod everytime.